# Function closures with mapslices

Tags: closures, julia

In the code snipped below, functions `f` and `g` are returning different values. From reading the code, you would expect them to behave the same. I am guessing it is to do with closure of `v -> innerprodfn(m, v)`. How do I do it to get the desired behaviour where `f` and `g` return the same values.

```
type Mat{T<:Number}
  data::Matrix{T}
end

innerprodfn{T}(m::Mat{T}, v::Array{T}) = i -> (m.data*v)[i]
innerprodfn{T}(m::Mat{T}, vv::Matrix{T}) = mapslices(v->innerprodfn(m, v), vv, 1)

m = Mat(collect(reshape(0:5, 2, 3)))
v = collect(reshape(0:11, 3, 4))
f = innerprodfn(m, v[:,1])
g = innerprodfn(m, v)[1]
m.data * v 
# 10  28  46  64
# 13  40  67  94
[f(1) g(1); f(2) g(2)]
# 10  64
# 13  94
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an explanation for the observed behavior, but on a recent nightly version of Julia one gets the expected result.

On 0.5, a workaround is to use a comprehension:

```
innerprodfn{T}(m::Mat{T}, vv::Matrix{T}) = [innerprodfn(m, vv[:,i]) for i in indices(vv, 2)]
```

Of course, this works on 0.6 as well.